# php7 print html table (barcode) to network printer

Tags: php, html, printing, html-table, php-7

I'm new to PHP and searched for a solution, but nothing solved my problem. I use PHP Version 7.3.0 and so far, my code creates a barcode using tables. (there's more code above, this is just how the final output(what I want to print) gets generated)

```
$html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>"; 
for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2) // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
$html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div>"; 
return "$html<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2><b>$text</table>";
```

Example how the page looks like after the barcode creation:

[image: Barcode]

What I am looking for is a way how I can print this on a network printer. (static IP) Is there any possible way to do this without any other downloads? If not, what do I need for it to work in php7? Printing it on a label Printer is also possible if that is easier.

Thank you.

Comment: there is some tricks to do this but i'm not sure you can do that dynamically. But to me the best way is to build a pdf and just display it, not force download it, and the user will have the possibility to print it directly

Comment: @MacBooc thing is I actually wanted to know how to print something to understand how it works, so I can by myself go for the next step and use it on a label printer. In the end, my website should generate that barcode and print it on a zebra label printer. I don't think that is possible with your solution.

Comment: If you wonder how to fix this issue, visit the link below. The solution is pretty easy. Answer to this question is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55103631/8801183)